# Using the operator module to automate the construction of magic methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a class that will hold an expression for later evaluation.  For example, the following class can hold expressions involving addition and multiplication.

```
import operator as op

class Expr(object):
    def __init__(self, func = lambda x: x):
        self.expr = func

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.expr(x)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Expr(lambda x: op.sub(self.expr(x), other))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Expr(lambda x: op.mul(self.expr(x), other))

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        # Subtraction is not commutative -> order matters
        return Expr(lambda x: op.sub(other, self.expr(x)))

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Expr(lambda x: op.mul(other, self.expr(x)))
```

We can use this class to delay the evaluation of an expression, e.g.

```
>>> e1 = Expr()
>>> e2 = 5*e1 - 4
>>> e2(3)
11
```

Note that order of evaluation is important for non-commutative operations like subtraction (see the evaluation of `5 - e1` below).

```
>>> es = (2*e1, e1*3, e1 - 3, 4 - e1, 2*e2-3)
>>> [expr(5) for expr in es]
[10, 15, 2, -1, 39]
```

The problem is that I want to implement such methods for almost all operators and doing this explicitly would be annoying and a clear violation of the DRY principle.

**Question:** How might I automate the process for implementing all arithmetic and Boolean operators using the functions in the `operator` module?

An acceptable solution would implement the following operations: `-`, `*`, negation (i.e. `-x`), `==`, and `>`.  I am mostly interested in a solution for Python 3, but a portable solution would be a bonus!

Comment: Iterate over the operators and their names and use setattr() to create that functionality for your class.

Comment: Consider having your `Expr` store `(function, args or (), kwargs or {})` separately instead of just as a single callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
import operator as op

class Expr(object):
    def __init__(self, func=lambda x: x):
        self.expr = func

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.expr(x)


def factory(name):
    def operator(self, other):
        return Expr(lambda x: getattr(op, name)(self.expr(x), other))
    def roperator(self, other):
        return Expr(lambda x: getattr(op, name)(other,self.expr(x)))
    return operator,roperator


for n in ["add", "sub", "mul","truediv"]:
    op,rop = factory(n)
    setattr(Expr, "__{}__".format(n), op)
    setattr(Expr, "__r{}__".format(n), rop)

e1 = Expr()
e2 = 2*e1 + 5
print(e2(3))
```

Comment: I think that the `__radd__` needs to flip other and the call to `self.expr`.  Correct?

Comment: @yardsale8 correct. I added it.

Comment: There is a bug in the original code (`or` is a restricted name).  Unfortunately, my edit caused another bug (reused the name `op`).  If `op, `rop` are changed to `o, ro` in all references in the loop, we get a correct solution.  Thanks for the help!